# Linking External Url in react-native app slow

Tags: android, hyperlink, react-native

Here is a snippet of the react-native app I am building:

```
<View style={styles.slider1}>
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => Linking.openURL(data[0].slides[1].backgroundImageLink)}>
<Image style={styles.image1} source={{uri: imageSlider1[1] +'?$poi$&sm=aspect&aspect=1.42:1&h='+ deviceHeight/3}}
   style={{width: deviceWidth, height: deviceHeight/3.1}} />
</TouchableHighlight>

<Text style={styles.heading2}>
<Text style={{color: data[0].slides[1].textColour}}>{data[0].slides[1].headline + "\n"}</Text>
</Text>
<Text style={styles.text2} onPress={() => Linking.openURL(data[0].slides[1].backgroundImageLink)}>{data[0].slides[1].callToActionLabel}</Text>
</View>
```

I have three Views like this part of a slider and a press on the image or on the call to action should open an external URL.
Response times when pressing the target areas are incredibly slow.
Test external urls are all point to google.com
Any idea why?
Thanks

Edit: React-native version is 0.26.2

I can't even say that the onPress event is picked up every time I press... I make sure not to cancel the gesture.
What would be the best way to find out what's going on CPU-wise? I have turned 'Show CPU Usage' but I am not sure how this is helpful as it doesn't seem linked to how I am interacting with my page.

Ultimately I have changed the code to:

```
<View style={styles.slider1} onPress={() => Linking.openURL(data[0].slides[0].backgroundImageLink)}>
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => Linking.openURL(data[0].slides[0].backgroundImageLink)}>
<Image style={styles.image1} source={{uri: imageSlider1[0] +'?$poi$&sm=aspect&aspect=1:1.25&w=' + deviceWidth}}
   style={{width: deviceWidth, height: deviceWidth}} />
</TouchableHighlight>
<Text style={styles.heading1} onPress={() => Linking.openURL(data[0].slides[0].backgroundImageLink)}><Text style={{color: data[0].slides[0].textColour}}>{data[0].slides[0].headline + "\n"}</Text></Text>
<View style={styles.CTA1} onPress={() => Linking.openURL(data[0].slides[0].backgroundImageLink)}>
<Text style={styles.text1}>{data[0].slides[0].callToActionLabel}</Text>
</View>
```

I really just want the event to trigger opening an external page.
It does so inconsistently.

Using xcode and same code, it reacts as expected - which is confusing.

Comment: Do you see an increase in CPU usage before or after pressing the areas?

Comment: What version of React Native? There's performance issue reported with 0.27: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7995

Comment: Same issue. Any solution?